# Pass a list to python library in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I need to pass a list to Python library from Robot Framework test case. I've checked manual [List variables syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#list-variables) but it is working not how I'm expecting.
Attempt to create list

```
@{filters}    Test_one    Test_two
```

gives to different arguments but my python library expects one.
Attempt to pass list of one element by

```
@{filters}    Test_one
```

Gives list

> ['T', 'e', 's', 't', '_', 'o', 'n', 'e']

The desired result inside python lib should like this:

> ['Test_one', 'Test_two']

What have I missed? Please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So list variable should be created with @{} but passing to library should be done as scalar ${}. Original answer is [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robotframework-users/04og2BB0ZSg) .